# gazebo node arguments list

Tags: ros, gazebo, node, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm currently trying to launch simulations headless according to [this tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/RunningSimulatorHeadless), but there is only *empty_world_no_x.launch* as example showing -r option use.

In my case, I want to simulate Willow Garage world and others with walls to allow a pr2 doing SLAM. I successfully launch empty_world headless and manually spawned the wg walls located in gazebo_world/objects but I would use a launch file.
I tried adding -r in the wg_world_paused.launch loaded from pr2_wg_world.launch, but gazebo is quitting, so I guess that other '-s -1 -u' args are conflicting with '-r'.
Is there somewhere gazebo node arguments are described, that would allow me to understand what is exactly doing the pr2_wg_wolrd.launch file ?

========================================================================

Edit :
Thanks for answering. I try only with -r but still the same error :

```
gazebo: /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.2/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros
/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp:47:
static Ogre::ResourceGroupManager& Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton(): Assertion 'ms_Singleton' failed.
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 26497, exit code -6].
log files: /home/renaudo/.ros/log/043d1f9c-9819-11e1-9e9a-002219119be4/gazebo-1*.log
```

The world I try to load is wg_collada.world. Maybe it is not launchable in headless ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33418/gazebo-node-arguments-list/) by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on ROS Answers with karma: 697 on 2012-05-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-05-07**:
indeed this is a bug in electric.  [patched in kforge gazebo](http://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/hg/rev/a4b3ac405ea3), will release with [simulator_gazebo 1.4.15](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/ChangeList/1.4).  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First thing, if you run the following command, it will print help for you:

```
rosrun gazebo gazebo -h
```

I don't know why that those options would conflict with headless mode. It's possible that the reason you're having problems is because of the `-s -1` option that disables shared memory, but I find that unlikely.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1